# Can I use Azure AD user for authorization while using an application identity to access Azure Graph API?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4.6 application and I want to be able to use an application identity to provide access to the Azure Graph API behind the scenes, but I want to use Azure AD users for my applications authentication and authorization.

The end goal is to be able to have a user initially register using Google, Facebook, or enter their own username.  During this registration, my application would leverage the Graph API to create an Azure AD user behind the scenes.

Once registered, if the user logs on using Google, Facebook, or their own username, it will look up against the Azure AD users to retrieve groups or roles.

Is this possible, or even a good idea?  I'm open to other suggestions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible. Azure AD recently released Azure AD B2C (**b**usiness to **c**onsumer) to public preview. B2C will allow your users to sign up and sign in with consumer identity providers (e.g. Google, Facebook, etc.).

The sign *up* portion of this creates a special kind of user in Azure AD that has a reference to an identity in the consumer identity provider. The sign *in* portion of B2C allows users to authenticate with their corresponding identity provider, and that authentication is recognized in Azure AD.

The full documentation starts at: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-overview/, and a ASP.NET MVC sample is at: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet/.

Alternatively, if you want to do you own, off the top of my head, the best you can do is to build a mechanism where you associate a "regular" Azure AD user with the corresponding social identity provider (e.g. maintain a lookup table). Your users would sign in to your app using each identity provider's protocol, and when they've done so, you "artificially" link them to the corresponding Azure AD users. From Azure AD's perspective, however, these users would not actually be authenticated, so at best, you'd be using Azure AD as a place to store users and groups.

Comment: Microsoft is doing so much now that it is hard to wade through it all.  It's great, just tough to find what you need!  I was also looking at Azure Active Directory Access Control.  Access Control looked like a lot more configuration though.  This is perfect.  Not sure how I feel about using it in a production app though.

Comment: Also, it looks like it doesn't support AngularJS flow yet.  My app is a pretty simple SPA and I'm considering ripping out the angular just for this.

Comment: I would caution you against using ACS. It is no longer being developed, and features are being migrated to AAD. See here: 
http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2015/02/12/the-future-of-azure-acs-is-azure-active-directory.aspx
and
http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2013/06/22/azure-active-directory-is-the-future-of-acs.aspx

Comment: @Phillippe Signoret, Is B2C will be in addition to the regular ADAL or instead? 
I'm talking about this library  Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

Comment: @tatigo Depends on what you mean by "regular ADAL". ADAL is a *library* that abstraits certains aspects of obtaining and managing tokens with Azure AD using OAuth2/OpenID Connect, while Azure AD B2C is an enhancement to the Azure AD *service*. Depending on the  platform you're developing on, ADAL may already "just work" for a B2C-enabled application. The article I've linked to in the answer has a section that says more about ADAL.

Comment: The quick starts do not show sample for MVC6.  Anyone seen such a sample?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out the new [Azure B2C offering](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2015/09/16/azure-ad-b2c-and-b2b-are-now-in-public-preview.aspx), in preview, which supports the exact scenario you are asking about out of the box.